# Modifying css with awk/gawk

Tags: css, bash, awk, gawk

I am trying to modify the properties of a specify css style using awk/gawk. For example, how would I change the *right* property the style *cta_grad*?:

```
.cta_grad {
    cursor: pointer; 
    cursor: hand;
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 38px;
    right: 34px;
    width: 77px;
    height: 29px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url("images/cta_grad.png");
}
```

Here is something in bash I am looking for:

```
gawk -i inplace 'EDIT right VALUE OF cta_grad TO 14px' style.css
```

giving me:

```
right: 14px;
```

Also, I'd like to change the property name itself, eg: change *right* to *left*. Something like:

```
gawk -i inplace 'CHANGE right PROPERTY OF cta_grad TO left' style.css
```

giving me:

```
left: 34px;
```

Thanks

Comment: Why specifically with awk? Why are you using inplace to test? Have you made any attempt yourself?

Comment: @123 gawk fits in with the other code I am using, but I am happy to use sed if that works better.
I am not using inplace to test, no. 
I am able to remove/clear css styles using: 
gawk '/^}/{flag=""} /cta_grad/{flag=1;print;next} flag{next} 1' style.css 
but not target specific properties

Comment: That code has nothing to do with what your are trying to do though and is clearly just copied from your previous question with no attempt to actually understand what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

a non-robust way of implementing this with `awk` is

```
$ awk -v k="right:" '$1==k{sub(k,"left:")}1' file

.cta_grad {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 38px;
    left: 34px;
    width: 77px;
    height: 29px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url("images/cta_grad.png");
}

$ awk -v k="right:" '$1==k{sub($2,"14px;")}1' file

.cta_grad {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 38px;
    right: 14px;
    width: 77px;
    height: 29px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url("images/cta_grad.png");
}
```

but you're better off with using css-aware tools.